# PHP - Difference between 'use()' or 'global' to access a global variable in a closure?

Tags: php, scope, closures, anonymous-function

Is there any kind of performance or other difference between following two cases of accessing a global variable in a closure:

**Case 1:**

```
$closure = function() use ($global_variable) {
  // Use $global_variable to do something.
}
```

**Case 2:**

```
$closure = function() {
  global $global_variable; 
  // Use $global_variable to do something.
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is an important difference between your two examples:

```
$global_variable = 1;

$closure = function() use ($global_variable) {
    return $global_variable; 
};

$closure2 = function() {
    global $global_variable;
    return $global_variable;
};

$global_variable = 99;

echo $closure();    // this will show 1
echo $closure2();   // this will show 99
```

`use` takes the value of `$global_variable` during the definition of the closure while `global` takes the current value of `$global_variable` during execution.

`global` inherits variables from the global scope while `use` inherits them from the parent scope.

Comment: While this is correct, in many cases you want to pass an object instance to the closure. Objects are passed by reference, and any changes to the object's state **after** the closure's definition will be available in the closure.

Comment: In other words: `use` copies the value of a variable into the closure whereas  `global` "imports" the variable into the current scope

Answer (score 1):

`Use`keyword are in parent scope, while `global` and `$GLOBALS` are from everywhere.

That's mean if you use `global` you may not know if the value have changed, from where by what and what is the kind of the change.

You have more control by using `use`. So it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your title question has been well answered, so I'll skip that.

You pose a different question in the body though. Which has better performance?

I made a simple test that I tried in [PHP Sandbox](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/):

```php
<?php
$bool = true;

$one = function() use ($bool) {
    return $bool;
};

$two = function() {
    global $bool;
    return $bool;
};

for ($power = 1; $power <= 10000000; $power *= 10) {
    
    echo "loops = {$power}\n";

    $before = microtime(true);
    for ($i=0 ; $i<20000 ; $i++)
        $one();
    $after = microtime(true);
    $timeOne = ($after-$before)/$i;
    echo "{$timeOne} sec/one\n";
    
    
    $before = microtime(true);
    for ($i=0 ; $i<20000 ; $i++)
        $two();
    $after = microtime(true);
    $timeTwo = ($after-$before)/$i;
    echo "{$timeTwo} sec/two\n";
    
    echo "Winner: " . ($timeOne > $timeTwo ? 'one' : 'two') . "\n\n";
}
```

And the results are very inconclusive:

```
loops = 1
6.2644481658936E-8 sec/one
5.6242942810059E-8 sec/two
Winner: one

loops = 10
5.4049491882324E-8 sec/one
4.9102306365967E-8 sec/two
Winner: one

loops = 100
5.1343441009521E-8 sec/one
5.4597854614258E-8 sec/two
Winner: two

loops = 1000
5.5849552154541E-8 sec/one
5.2559375762939E-8 sec/two
Winner: one

loops = 10000
5.6040287017822E-8 sec/one
5.3608417510986E-8 sec/two
Winner: one

loops = 100000
5.8901309967041E-8 sec/one
4.960298538208E-8 sec/two
Winner: one

loops = 1000000
6.2298774719238E-8 sec/one
6.9999694824219E-8 sec/two
Winner: two

loops = 10000000
8.3756446838379E-8 sec/one
5.9354305267334E-8 sec/two
Winner: one
```

Perhaps `use` if a bit faster than `global`, but you probably should make the decision on which to use based on that. It's all about the use-case (no pun intended).

You have more control with `use` which is parent-scoped, so it's probably your best bet in most cases, but if you really need a variable from global scope, the answer is obvious.

Also note, that you can use `use` with anonymous (lambda) functions only (like in my testing example). If you want to have the same functionality in normally defined functions, then you need to have the variable in question as function parameter, but referenced by pointer. Beware, it's not without caveat. If your function makes any changes to the referenced variable, these change won't be local to the function. Here's an example.

```php
// ...
function three(&$var) {
    return $var;
}
```